# Ways for comparing start and stop pulses in time of flight

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, photodiode, proximity-sensor

I am using an LM358 as an astable multivibrator. I am pulsing an 850nm IR LED at 1 Hz. The IR LED has a carrier wave of 38 kHz generated by a 555 timer.

I have a 38 kHz IR TSOP as receiver. It outputs negative when the signal is received.

These send and receive circuits are very reliable, but now I want to combine them.

Here is where I could use advice.

I would like the LM358 pulse cycle (default 1 Hz) to be dependent on the start (IR Pulse) and stop (IR Receive) events. If an object is close the frequency of pulses increases, if it is farther away, they decrease. It does not need to be precise, but should be dependent on time of flight. I'm talking meters accuracy vs cm.

Since I am only using one of the amps on the LM358, I'd like to turn the other into a comparator that outputs some voltage that can manipulate the RC (resistor/capacitor) oscillator on the other side of the LM358 causing the pulses to speed up or decrease based on the timing difference.

My thoughts are the comparator output will help fill up the capacitor more quickly, but I am unsure how to configure the inverting and noninverting inputs with my two signal sources. One signal is the start pulse (+), the other signal the receive pulse (-).

If needed I can obviously flip the polarity of the start and stop signals, but to save on components I'd prefer not to.

Update:
I have attached two waveforms to show how I might extract the phase shift between the send and receive events. This shift will be dependent on the speed of light.

[image: JK FLIP FLOP]
[image: XOR GATE]

Comment: Not a single calculation, no schematics, no conceptual diagrams, and nothing from an oscilloscope for transmitter or receiver (from those that are *"very reliable"*?) Maybe [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXHa.png)? I just don't know what to say or add right now. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: I thought it would be simple to visualize without those things. I am new to the board and learning expectations users have. It's as simple as I've got a t.v. remote. I push a button it bounces off the wall and hits a tsop. which outputs (-). I need an analog method for comparing these Start and Stop events.

Comment: Interesting idea! Can you calculate what distance you would be able to measure? What would be the time of flight for a Kilo-meter away target? Would the IR reach 1 Km and come back to the sensor?

Comment: In theory, its basically just a range finder without digital information or precise measurements, but I'm only using it for laser echo location out to 40meters. I was using amplitude to tell how far away objects were, but there are issues with this method such as mirrors sounding very close and dark objects sounding very far away. If I  make the echo pulses dependent on time of flight it will be much improved.

Rangefinders already work to the limits that the FDA will let the emitters operate at without hurting human eyes. My Lieca Rangefinder works almost to 1km during the daylight.

Comment: @Tech-Com It may be. And It isn't as though I haven't participated in very similar projects. But here I won't attempt to project my experiences. If you write more, great. I may take a shot then. (A suggestion I may have is that you thoroughly investigate the technologies applied in the Lieca Rangefinder, perhaps.) Otherwise, others can deal with the existing level if information, if they want. I've other things I'd rather be doing. This is just my own personal choice. No necessary reflection about anyone else, including you.

Comment: Light travels at around 3.3ns per metre.  How do you propose to measure this with the likes of a tsop and a lm358 op-amp? Some McGyver tricks maybe?

Comment: The lm358 might not work. Texas Instruments has a TLV3604 they market for this purpose. The datasheet shows a simple receiver with comparator, but does not show how it interfaces with the emitter. Also texas instrument document snoaa63.pdf provides some basic guidance and feasibility but not enough for me to put the tlv3604 in a circuit or other similar comparator.
I don't need it to measure the time or be precise. I just need it to tell there is a difference between the Start and Stop events and have a voltage change based on these differences.

Comment: To save on components you should simply use ICs dedicated to TOF measurements :D however it's not really clear what you want to do, could you add some kind of block schematic at least?

Comment: The TSOP IR receivers have a significant jitter based on the light conditions. I've built an IR data link using these modules (pulse-position modulation), and the jitter was normally between 3 to 6 cycles, which is 80-160uS. That would mean at least ~24km of error.

Comment: I will try to get a diagram or schematic together. I believe I may be inching towards a solution. I believe a Phase Shift Detector, may be able to output the difference in the start and stop events. I'm also experimenting with summing, multiplying, and differential amplification of the two signals just to see what happens.

Comment: I think it would be easier to do with a modulated laser (IR is very "dispersive") and a "long distance" "fast receiver". The receiver would need "optical system". Very fast comparator also needed.

Comment: @Tech-Com What I'll write isn't meant in any way to be disparaging. It's just meant to quickly get across why you should consider writing a lot more than you have. That's all. So please don't take it in any personal way. I'm just prodding you for more. You've added a conceptual diagram, which I'd already (as you correctly surmised) had in my head from the first reading. It's just a cartoon, though. Of course it is relatively easy to generate a useful output if you are given perfect pictures like that. I only wish I ever was handed that, in practice.

Comment: @Tech-Com In any case, if that's all it is then you may simply gate a current source into a integrator and sample/measure the result. Offset, gain, and charge injection/removal from switching may be issues. But this simple idea, ignoring those issues, matches the cartooned inputs -- rather all of it very idealized. In reality, there is the optical system design and doing what can be done to remove optical leakage or unwanted wavelengths or a host of other optical issues. There's the transducers involved and their imperfections and driver/receiver non-idealities. Etc. Measurement isn't easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the phase shift with just one 74HTC00 according schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0rplZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Feed the output to RC filter. Output of RC filter connect to voltage to frequency converter (one Op-Amp) what generates the desired frequency.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. How will the ouput differ from an XOR gate? Does this configuration function as a XOR gate when inputs are opposite polarity rather than the same?

Comment: The XOR will generate two pulses per period, always when signal differs. This one only when Input_1=high and Input_2=low.

Comment: I ordered the parts, and I think your explanation shows a clear understanding and will likely be the solution. I was getting 2 pulses with the XOR gate I made from 5 transistors. I thought the extra pulse would just charge the capacitor more quickly and not cause any other issues, but now I see it would likely nullify since one pulse occurs when the capacitor is discharging and the other pulse when it is charging. I look forward to testing the recommended IC.